# How can i search for same value of different row from one single query on MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this table 'post_meta'

```
post_id name        value
87      my_keyname1 randval1
87      my_keyname2 randval2
```

I want to search for 2 different row and wants to return a single post_id. I know all the values of the 'name' and 'value' and i want to satisfy my query that i get the same post_id with 2 different 'name' and 'value' row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter the table only for the records of interest and then group by `post_id`, your desired results are those groups that contain exactly two distinct records:

```
SELECT   post_id
FROM     post_meta
WHERE    (name = 'my_keyname1' AND value = 'randval1')
      OR (name = 'my_keyname2' AND value = 'randval2')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT name, value) = 2
```

Should it be guaranteed that the name or value of each record within a group is unique, you can replace `COUNT(DISTINCT name, value)` with `COUNT(*)` for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM post_meta
WHERE (name = 'my_keyname1' AND value = 'randval1')
OR (name = 'my_keyname2' AND value = 'randval2');
```

Comment: This will only query for 1 row. I need 2 rows with same post_id that matches my name,value. I need to satisfy my query that the second row has also that value. This is a post meta on wordpress.

Comment: I edited my question i hope you get my point kinda having problem explaining my query.